How to resample an ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine using bicubic method
I am trying to resample a Sentinel 2A ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine using the bicubic method. However, the resulted map is weird. I am using the folloiwng code. I apprecite if somebody help me to fix this issue:
In the following code, I define an area of interest (aoi) and a fucntion to get Sentinel 2A images for the aoi and a specific date. The function also clip and mosaic the ImageCollectoin. The bicubic method is used to resample the ImageCollection.
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var aoi = 
    /* color: #98ff00 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-82.14606816037433, 42.900619674967885],
          [-82.14606816037433, 42.48476153151389],
          [-81.48963505490558, 42.48476153151389],
          [-81.48963505490558, 42.900619674967885]]], null, false);
   
// Show aoi on map
Map.addLayer(aoi, {color: 'yellow'});

// Funcion to clip the sentinel bands
function clipping(im){
   return im.clip(aoi)
}

// Function to get Sentinel 2A images for an aoi and specific date
function getSentinel2WithinDateRange(start,end,aoi){
  var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                    .filterBounds(aoi)
                    .filterDate(start, end)
                    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                    .map(maskS2clouds);
                    
  return sentinel2.map(clipping).mosaic()
}

var date_start = '2024-05-29'
var date_end = '2024-06-30'

var collections = getSentinel2WithinDateRange(date_start, date_end,aoi)
print('Collection info', collections.getInfo())

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.centerObject(aoi)

Map.addLayer(collections, visualization, 'RGB');

// Resample the collection using bicubic method
var resampled = collections.resample('bicubic')

print ('resample', resampled.getInfo())

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

// Display the resampled images
Map.addLayer(resampled,visualization);


I posted the question in https://gis.stackexchange.com/ and got the solution. Please see the following link for the solution:
The solution of the problem 
